# Kotlin unexpected `unresolved reference`

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm a beginner to Kotlin, and here's my code:

```
class C(val boy: Int = 0) {
    fun <T, E> boy(i: Int) = i
}

fun girl(b1: Boolean, b2: Boolean) = println("boy($b1, $b2)")

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    val A = 234 // see? A defined!
    val B = 345 // see? B defined!
    val c = C(123) // c is also defined!

    girl(c.boy < A, B > A) // hey look at here
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA gives me:

- `unresolved reference: A`
- `unresolved reference: B`
- `unresolved reference: c`

At the line `hey look at here`.

I think my code is syntactically correct, what's wrong?

Comment: One thing about this question bugs me thou - how could you miss all other kotlinc errors on that line that actually explain what happens? Hm..

Comment: Because I didn't actually compile, I only see errors given in the first line in IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You stumped on a very rare case of syntactic ambiguity. I think it is a first for SO, congrats!

Your initial syntax is technically correct, but in this contexts it also can be interpreted as an attempt to call `c.boy<A,B>`. Since the compiler didn't know what you meant, it assumed you wanted the function call.

The easiest fix is adding parenthesis as you did or rearranging the expressions:

```
girl(c.boy < A, A < B)
```

P.S. Same thing can happen in C#, so it is not unique to Kotlin

Comment: Java doesn't have such issue LOL

Comment: Actually it is a brilliant design on the Kotlin's part. Do you remember how you call a generic method in Java?  With generics in the wrong place `c.<A, B>boy(A)`? That is cased by the same problem.

Comment: I think this language design in Java is intended to avoid this conflict.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think code like in your example is very common, so optimizing for the common case where there is no ambiguity seems like a good choice to me.

Comment: Java would done it too if it were designed with generics from the beginning

Comment: Same thing can't happen in C#, because `boy` is either a property, or a method, never both. In OP's question, the compiler can't tell if `boy` is a property or a generic method, hence the error.

Comment: @DannyChen It is possible to create a similar puzzler in C# with a similar behaviour

Comment: @voddan In that case, it is definitely a compile error, under no circumstance it can compile, unlike in Kotlin it should compile if you consider `boy` as a property.

Comment: @DannyChen Kotlin's properties can not have explicit type parameters, so no

Answer (score 2):

Well.. I solved these errors by adding a pair of braces:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    val A = 234
    val B = 345
    val c = C(123)

    girl((c.boy < A), B > A) // hey look at here
}
```

But I still wonder why my code above doesn't work

Edit: see the other answer

Comment: This makes no sense, you can't call the method `boy` without parentheses. Does this actually compile?

Comment: Ah, I missed the `val boy` part. Your initial version did not work because the Kotlin compiler read `c.boy < A, B>` as part of a call to the function `C.boy(Int)` with generic type parameters `A` and `B`. Since no classes `A` and `B` were present, the compiler complained about unresolved references.
In all honesty, this looks like you were deliberately trying to confuse the compiler ;-)